# Virtual hosting on CentOS

Tags: apache, dns, linux

I have a CentOS machine running Apache. I have a few virtual hosts set up and they run just fine. An example of a setup that's working fine is:

```
<VirtualHost 10.10.10.38:80>
    ServerName site.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site
    <Directory /var/www/html/site>
        Options -Indexes
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from {IP address list}
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /etc/httpd/logs/site.error_log
    CustomLog /etc/httpd/logs/site.access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 10.10.10.38:443>
        ServerName site.domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site
        <Directory /var/www/html/site>
            Options -Indexes
            Order deny,allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from {IP address list}
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /etc/httpd/logs/site.error_log
        CustomLog /etc/httpd/logs/site.access_log common
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile    /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key
    </VirtualHost>
```

This is in

> /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

I have another entry almost exactly like that except that

> site.domain.com

becomes

> site1.domain.com

and points to a different folder in /var/www/html/.

I cannot get the browser to locate site1.domain.com. The

> site.access_log

file is empty. I assume that means that the browser is not able to resolve the DNS. What am I missing out on?

Comment: did you add an entry to your name server?

Comment: Yes. I added an entry to the /etc/hosts file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a network error. Resolved!